# Alternative for, conditional regex with break, in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I was trying to implement the conditional Regex in the following format, `(a)?d(?(1)b|c)`, to match the following strings:

```
adb
dc
```

Explanation:
If the string has 'a' for the first character, then it should end with 'b' otherwise end with 'c'. With 'd' being in both strings in the middle.

How can I implement the same in Javascript?

Note:
In my real application all 4 groups, 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd' are some other Regex patterns.

Comment: I mean; `/^([a]{1}.*[d]{1}.*[b]{1})|([^a]{1}.*[d]{1}.*[c]{1})$/im` - this works (see [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) to test this), but there is a better way, just don't know it

Comment: @CanO'Spam 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd' are long patterns, so prefer not to repeat them.

Answer (score 0):

```
/.*d(.*b(?<=a.*))|(.*c(?<=[^a].*))/g
```

works, however it might not be compatible with every browser (only works in V8 browsers). For regex testing, I recommend you [regex101](https://regex101.com/). This pattern first test if d is contained, then if it ends with b and starts with a or if it ends with c end starts with not a using the [lookbehind feature](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind)

Comment: It does not work because "'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd' are long patterns, so prefer not to repeat them."